# Migrating to another continent between vaccines

Tags: travel, immunizations

I am planning migrate from overseas to my homeland when my infant becomes around 3 months old, she is 1 months old now. Though she will start some vaccines soon in two weeks. However, we cannot finish all, so in the middle of some vaccines (e.g. rotavirus, Hepatitis B, HiB), we will migrate.

My question: is there any problem with getting the first dose away, and remaining doses in my homeland country? Any pros/cons, anything I should be careful, such as should I wait sometime like a week or so after the she got her dose before travel?

I asked a few doctors, they said it is totally fine, though I heard a guy whose  child died, because doctors on the both side did some assumptions, and overlooked the risk factors.

Answer (score 2):

Every vaccination should be documented in your child's [Carte Jaune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Jaune) - make sure your current pediatrician issues one. This will document the dates, type of vaccine and manufacturer, any other doctor should be able to continue the vaccination routine according to national or international standards.

This document will in the future also record vaccinations outside the "standard procedure", e.g. those your child gets prior to traveling to other parts of the world.

Apart from this, only the normal risks (and benefits!) of vaccinating apply, which is a completely different topic and need not be discussed here. For your immediate travel plans note that *some* babies *might* be a bit queasy or run a slight fever during the following one or two days, but that should be about it. And not all children react - mine didn't, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I can't personally testify to the absence of medical risks, but we've done exactly what you describe with our 2 youngest kids, and I think with our 3 older kids as well.

Unless I disagreed with the importance of the vaccines, I wouldn't delay getting them due to travel plans. On the contrary, it makes sense to me that all of our traveling adds to their risk, and the vaccines will help minimize that risk.

Good luck!